# Error using Deno Fresh NPM package and Datepicker

Tags: deno, freshjs

The component is created in the components folder, and then used in an island component

I have tried two ways of using the lib react-datepicker:

- **1:** Adding the import in deno.json and using it.
- This way the datepicker just not appear on the screen
- Vscode points shows the following error:
  [image]
- 2: Using with npm: indicator directly onto the file
- This way deno shows a massive error in the terminal
  [image]

My code:

```js
import DatePicker from 'npm:react-datepicker@4.23.0'
import {useState} from 'preact/hooks'

export function DatePickerA({name, title, required}: {name: string, title: string, required?: boolean}) {
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
    
    return (
        <label className='my-5 flex flex-col gap-y-2' for={name}>
            <span className={`text-dark-blue`}>{title}</span>
            <DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)} />
        </label>
    )
}
```

How can I use react-datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried similar things, sometimes it works, other times it doesn't. Here is what I got working for react-datepicker.

This works functionally but the types will need some fixing. The main thing you need to do is update your `imports` in your `deno.json` file, making sure the preact version matches throughout:

```json
{
  "imports": {
    ...
    "preact": "https://esm.sh/preact@10.18.1",
    "preact/": "https://esm.sh/preact@10.18.1/",
    ...
    "react": "https://esm.sh/preact@10.18.1/compat",
    "react-dom": "https://esm.sh/preact@10.18.1/compat",
    "react/jsx-runtime": "https://esm.sh/preact@10.18.1/compat",
    "react-datepicker": "https://esm.sh/react-datepicker@4.23.0?external=react,react-dom&target=es2022"
  }
}
```

Then since this uses custom CSS and deno imports don't work for CSS, we need to include that in our project manually:

_app.tsx

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-datepicker@4.23.0/dist/react-datepicker.css"
/>
```

You will want to wrap the react `DatePicker` with an HTML tag (e.g. div) or the flex-col will mess with it. I also added `showIcon` just to test that it works as well.

Here is what it looks like in Fresh with that all setup:

[image]

For reference, see these links:

- [Experiment using Radix UI in Fresh](https://github.com/hapaxlife/test-fresh-radix-ui)
- [denoland/fresh - preact-compat GitHub discussion](https://github.com/denoland/fresh/discussions/432)
- [denoland/fresh - issues with radix-ui GitHub issue](https://github.com/denoland/fresh/issues/1530)